# How to become vegan if I belong to sub-arctic region?

Tags: veganism

I want to become vegan but my environment doesn't allow me as I belong to Oymyakonsky district, Sakha Republic. We people of Oymyakonsky eat lot of meat and fish to keep ourselves warm and also because there's no vegetation here. Is there any way so that I can become vegan?

Comment: Welcome! I often wonder how people might avoid eating animal foods in regions with little vegetation. I imagine it would be a great challenge and disruption to one's way of life. I am very interested in your findings.

Comment: Himalayan regions are full of vegetarians although cut off from rest for several months during winter. They survive on storage of food items, milk from mountainous cows n animals , essential supplies during winter etc. Where there is a will, there is a way.

Comment: @sbharti Himalayan regions have bit vegetation. Oymyakons are unable to grow crops, therefore our diet basically consists of reindeer, fish and horse meat.

Comment: Yes it's going to be difficult. You'd need to rely on imports. You'd not get fresh vegetables. But sun dried or boiled and dried ones are common practices. Grains and lentils could be your staple diet. If you get fresh supplies during winter then it's great. I'd also advise to add dairy, although you mentioned vegan. Because it's a practical problem and one solution may not fit all, you'd have to try and test. Cost could be another problem. In usa ppl keep packaged cooked food refrigerated which lasts for months. If you write, would love to hear your experience with veganism in Sakha.

Answer (score 4):

If you help create a demand for vegan products, then the supply stores around will respond. However, it may take a village. I live in Scandinavia, and have noticed the uptick in vegan/vege products in the past five years as the demand from consumers has increased.

You can also make the argument that vegan products store better in your environment. Dried beans last years in storage, and can be made without heavy salting or other preservatives with a few days prep. It is also much cheaper to buy and store beans than it is cured meats (at least from my perspective). Try to encourage others to diversify their protein intake for both health and economic reasons, which will increase the demand for vegan products in your stores.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot become vegan in practice by not eating aminal products, then you can become vegan in spirit by fighting for animal rights.  By fighting for humane treatment of the animals that you have to consume in order to survive.

There are many activities on the internet that you can participate in, that promote animal welfare and that try to stop animal cruelty.

Comment: Will it not be hypocrisy? I tried to register myself for campaign to protect animal lives. The authority rejected my application stating reason that I'm non-vegetarian.